# Gnome Shell randomly crashes after hours of use

Tags: 17.04, crash, ubuntu-gnome, logout, gnome-shell

I don't even really know how to start diagnosing it. I'll be sitting doing something, the UI will lock up, frames will disappear from windows, window depth will randomly change. If I'm watching a YouTube video, it'll keep playing for a second before dying, and then I'll be kicked to the login screen. Does anyone know what could be causing this?

`neofetch` output:

````
          ./o.                      aidan@viselik 
        .oooooooo                   ------------- 
      .oooo```soooo                 OS: Ubuntu 17.04 x86_64 
    .oooo`     `soooo               Kernel: 4.10.0-26-generic 
   .ooo`   .o.   `\/ooo.            Uptime: 2 days, 1 hour, 34 mins 
   :ooo   :oooo.   `\/ooo.          Packages: 2597 
    sooo    `ooooo    \/oooo        Shell: bash 4.4.7 
     \/ooo    `soooo    `ooooo      Resolution: 3440x1440 
      `soooo    `\/ooo    `soooo    DE: GNOME 
./oo    `\/ooo    `/oooo.   `/ooo   WM: GNOME Shell 
`\/ooo.   `/oooo.   `/oooo.   ``    WM Theme: Adwaita-tweaks-dark 
  `\/ooo.    /oooo     /ooo`        Theme: Adwaita-tweaks-dark [GTK2/3] 
     `ooooo    ``    .oooo          Icons: Papirus [GTK2/3] 
       `soooo.     .oooo`           Terminal: gnome-terminal 
         `\/oooooooooo`             CPU: Intel i7-6700 (8) @ 4.0GHz 
            ``\/oo``                GPU: Intel Integrated Graphics 
                                    GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1070 
                                    Memory: 4692MiB / 32053MiB
````

Comment: Don't know if this is related: In my case, is working fine for hours (on Wayland, btw), but without any previous indication, it simply restarts itself, taking me back to the login screen, and half the time this happens, it comes back with all extensions disabled.